# Why does this Python boolean comparison return a triple?

Tags: python, boolean, behavior

I was playing around on the command-line for Python 2.7.8, where I encountered this behavior:

```
>>> "902".isdigit() == True
True
>>> "902".isdigit(), "2".isdigit() == True
(True, True)
>>> "902".isdigit(), "2".isdigit() == True,True
(True, True, True)
>>> ("902".isdigit(), "2".isdigit()) == (True,True)
```

I found this surprising. I would have expected `>>> "902".isdigit(), "2".isdigit() == True,True` to simply return `True` as if I had surrounded both expressions in parentheses to make them into tuples. Why does Python return this tuple of booleans, rather than a single one? What boolean comparisons does this tuple represent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because:

```
"902".isdigit(), "2".isdigit() == True,True
```

is interpreted as:

```
("902".isdigit(), ("2".isdigit() == True), True)
```

Note that you shouldn't test booleans with `==`; a more pythonic way to write the test is:

```
"902".isdigit() and "2".isdigit()
```

Answer (score 4):

To add to jonrsharpe's answer:

The reason it is interpreted this way is because the Python parser has no way to determine whether:

```
 "902".isdigit(), "2".isdigit() == True, True
```

was meant to be:

```
("902".isdigit(), ("2".isdigit() == True), True)
```

or:

```
("902".isdigit(), "2".isdigit()) == (True, True)
```

Basically there is no way to (*from a grammar perspective*) to determine this without using **explicit** parentheses.

See: [Full Grammar Specification](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html) (*but you'd need some background in BNF/EBNF grammars*).

Comment: Small note: the interpreter does know how it has to be parsed through the priority of the operations. This is why you get a tuple of three elements.